# How can i use a variable passed using render in ejs to be added as a css inline style value?

Tags: css, node.js, ejs

I need to pass a background color code to be added as a inline background color style property inside an ejs code .

I am passing the color code like below :

In `main-controller.js`:

```js
  let primaryColor = 'red';
  ejs.renderFile("views/myfile.ejs", {primaryColor, path: '/' }
```

In `myfile.ejs`:

```html
<html>
      <body style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color: 
       <%=primaryColor%>">
       <%=primaryColor%>
      </body>
</html>
```

[image]
This is the problems screen in vs code:
[image: This is the problems screen in vs code:]

In the above problem, i am able to print the value in resultant html, but the value cant be set as a background color to the body.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working on my machine.

I'm using express and ejs packages.

Try this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  let c = 'red';
  res.render("./main.ejs", { c, path: '/' });  
});
```

```
<html>
  <body style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color:<%= c %>;">
    <h1>
      <%= c %>
    </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: this is the result into the browser]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that's not the issue. i have updated the variable and error got while giving <%=%> syntax inside 'style' attribute.

Comment: The solution you provided is not binding the value . Can you please suggest any other alternatives?

Comment: Still no luck. i tried those options. Background-color itself is not showing along with other styles like width and height

Comment: Thanks @niccord for your time . Now its working fine. Donno why it was not getting reflected earlier . :-D

Comment: maybe `res.render` is better than `ejs.renderFile` :)